# Node, ExpressJS, vhost - Running Multiple Apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to use Node/ExpressJS to serve multiple apps, and I'm coming from an IIS background. The issue I'm having is based around restarting individual apps, without restarting all apps.

In IIS, I would simply click on the app (in the 'sites' list) and click on restart, which would restart only that app, leaving all others up and running.

This is what I have...

Server:

```
// index.js

require('console.table');

var _ = require('underscore-contrib');
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost')

var app = express();

var config = require("./config.json");

var websitesStart = function(website){
    if (website.live) {
        var host = vhost(website.domain, require(website.folder))
        app.use(host);
    }
}

_.each(config.websites, websitesStart);

app.listen(config.port, function(){
    console.log('Web Server Running, Port:' + config.port);
    console.table(config.websites);
});
```

Config:

```
// config.json
{
    "port": "8080",
    "websites": [
        {
            "name": "App 1",
            "live": "true",
            "domain": "app1.uk",
            "folder": "../apps/app1"
        },{
            "name": "App 2",
            "live": "true",
            "domain": "app2.uk",
            "folder": "../apps/app2"
        },{
            "name": "App 3",
            "live": "true",
            "domain": "app3.uk",
            "folder": "../apps/app3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Running `node index.js` starts all my apps just fine.

If I make a change to some code in App 2 for example, how would I restart only that app..? Leaving apps 1 and 3 running..?

**UPDATE:** I'm running on a Windows OS, so PM2 isn't really an option as it's only in beta.

**UPDATE 2** I would really like to run all the apps on port 80, like I can in IIS. Wouldn't I need to use different ports if I ran each app as a different ExpressJS app (running them as separate processes/services)..?

Comment: Did you think to use nginx? nginx has a concept of reverse proxy, and it can help for this

Comment: I've just checked the http://nginx.org/ website. Under "Tested OS and platforms" is says "Windows XP, Windows Server 2003". We're running Server 2012. To be honest, it feels like a Linux thing, whereas I'm looking to use Node/Express on Windows.

Comment: Understand, but worth it checked this option. Nginx is very robust and marry very well with node and express. I use in Linux and Windows servers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PM2 module](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#process-management) for process management.
Just describe your apps in package.json and start them all like:

```
./node_modules/.bin/pm2 start package.json
```

After you can use this to restart one app:

```
./node_modules/.bin/pm2 restart  <app_name|id|'all'|json_conf>
```

So you don't need "websitesStart" function at all.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Windows (sorry, should've said that), and I've already looked at PM2, and it's only in beta. I need something I can run in production.

Comment: So, by your answer, I'm guessing that you recommend running my apps in separate ExpressJS apps, and using some sort of process/service manager..? I guess I was just trying to emulate IIS.

Comment: Just a thought - if I have multiple ExpressJS apps running as separate services, one for each app, won't they all need different ports..? I really wanted all the apps to run on port 80...

Comment: @CrusaderLtd yes, I think that it's better to separate them to different processes to make them more independent. If you will have some unhandled error, you will restart only one app to avoid resource leaking, but all other apps will not crush.

I can also suggest you to use Nginx for static files delivery (clientside js, css, img), so you can also bind ports in Nginx config like:

app1.uk:80 -> localhost:3000
app2.uk:80 -> localhost:3001

Of course the best and easiest solution is just to use linux on production server.